# Can I only see the last tag synonym suggestion?

Tags: support, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

Today I tried to suggest the tag synonyms below:

- [laravel-views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-views) to [laravel-blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-blade)
- [guzzlehttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guzzlehttp) to [guzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guzzle)

This is the first time I have suggested tag synonyms. I thought both tags are duplicated, that's why I created them. Views in Laravel are named Blades, and [guzzlehttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guzzlehttp) has guidance in its tag excerpt that says it is a 'duplicate tag'.

I just want to know why my [pending approval](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested) only shows the last suggestion only ([guzzlehttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guzzlehttp))? Does that mean my first suggestion ([laravel-views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-views)) has been declined or can I only see the last suggestion?

Here is my pending approval screenshot:

[image: screenshot of pending approvals]

Comment: I can see both of them. They're at the top of the list on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested Neither has been approved or rejected; in fact, neither has garnered any votes.

Comment: so why I can only see one?

Comment: I don't know? Maybe you have a search filter in place?

Comment: @CodyGray looks like the pending approval (tag-synonyms) page only shows tags that the user can vote, or I dunno... I see [different tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyJwc.png). (And of course, mods can approve single-handedly)

Comment: @CodyGray no, I havent search filter. I updated screenshot with full url and filter form

Comment: It only shows tag synonyms that you can vote on, yes, @AndrewT. But I'm pretty sure Muhammad meets the necessary criteria to vote on a suggestion if he was able to propose it. The tag synonym suggestion system is pretty broken, but I don't think it's so broken that the rep requirements for voting are different from those for submission.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree. Though, currently, the suspicious thing is if the voting actually requires 5 or 6 scores (i.e. "5 or more" or "more than 5"). The OP has exactly 5 scores on [tag:laravel-blade] while 7 scores on [tag:guzzle]